# How to use a method of a class from a pointer on an instance of this class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a class `ClassA` and a class `ClassB.
In`ClassA`one of the data members is a pointer on an instance of`ClassB`.
I want to define a method in`ClassA`that uses a method of the instance of`ClassB`, how can I do this ?

*hpp files*

```
class ClassA
{
    public:
       type ClassA::do_something_using_a_method_of_class_B();

    private:
       ClassB* instanceB;
}

class ClassB
{
    public:
        type ClassB::method_of_class_B();
}
```

*cpp files*

```
type  ClassA::do_something_using_a_method_of_class_B()
{ 
    return instanceB.method_of_class_B(); 
}
```

Comment: I'd do it this way:  `type  ClassA::do_something_using_a_method_of_class_B()
{  if (!instanceB) throw BadThingHappened(); return instanceB->method_of_class_B(); 
}`

Comment: Indeed it works, please put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
type ClassA::do_something_using_a_method_of_class_B() {
  if (!instanceB) throw BadThingHappened();
  return instanceB->method_of_class_B();
}
```

Or if you have an appropriate and good default vale for type:

```
type ClassA::do_something_using_a_method_of_class_B() {
  if (!instanceB) return type{};
  return instanceB->method_of_class_B();
}
```